# Variable in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, pickadate

here is my code:

```
$('#date').pickadate({
    format: 'mmmm d, yyyy',
    disable: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    ]
});
```

the "disable" means it will disable the days of week 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. this is the code that does not work:

```
<input type="text" id="numbers" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5">

<script>
var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value;

$('#date').pickadate({
    format: 'mmmm d, yyyy',
    disable: [
        numbers
    ]
});
</script>
```

i want to use the numbers in the variable because it can be dynamic. why does it not work with the variable `numbers`? how can i do this? thanks.

Comment: is there an error? Can you create a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net site, please. That'll make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably expecting numbers, not a string with commas:

```
[ "1, 2, 3, 4" ] !== [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Try this instead:

```
var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value.split(',').map(function(val) {
   return parseInt(val.trim(), 10);
});

$('#date').pickadate({
    format: 'mmmm d, yyyy',
    disable: numbers 
});
```

Comment: Rather have it as Number instead of parseInt. Just a feeling. What do you think?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I think the result is the same either way, no? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah. You've also considered the base as decimal. Interesting. Now I feel your code is perfect. This makes sense. You cannot use float as date. Thanks man. Adds to knowledge.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal good point, decimal likely wouldn't work here so `parseInt` is probably preferable. Thanks for the comment and glad to help! :-)

Comment: what's the difference between your answer and aletzo? why do you use split and map and parseInt? it seems like more work and code rather than just using split?

Comment: You nailed the difference: they chose to use an array of strings, I opted for type-safety for a numeric operation. What I posted is a tiny bit more work, but it avoids some easily preventable problems that implicit type coercion can cause.

Comment: The difference is the way of doing things. What happens when the input has values like 3.2 instead of 3? This is by far the most correct way to solve your problem @baileyJchoi.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal yes but if the number is going to be either 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, it is safe to use just split? is there a performance difference? even a little?

Comment: Yes it would be safe provided the values are correct. Not sure about performance, but I feel the performance of Map function will be a bit slower. Not sure though.

Comment: Unless you are preforming this operation thousands of times on page load, the performance difference is completely negligible.

Comment: If your user types "1,2,3,4" then the other solution won't work, it's splitting specifically on `", "` comma + space, it would fail if the user typed a floating point number into the input. Either way you are going to have to split on comma and map over the result to remove spaces and/or convert to `Number` unless you can 100% force your users to always comma + space separate the numbers.

Comment: okay thanks everyone. This is not working though: `var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value.split(',');`. `disable: numbers` how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you get them from the value they're strings, you need an array.

```js
$('#getinfo').on('click',function(){

var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
    numbers = numbers.split(' ').join(); // remove spaces
    numbers = numbers.split(','); // convert to array
    alert(numbers);
    console.log(numbers);
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="numbers" />
<button id="getinfo">Get Info</button>
```

Now you can use the variable there.

Comment: Be sure to also look at aletzo's answer: You need to directly pass the `numbers` variable to `disable`, not inside another array.

Answer (score 1):

In your code :

```
var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
```

numbers is not an array, its a string with value "1,2,3,4,5". To make it an array you need to use the split function:

```
var numbersArray = numbers.split(',');
```

Then you can use numbersArray with disable like so:

```
$('#date').pickadate({
    format: 'mmmm d, yyyy',
    disable: numbersArray
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array with one item that is a string with the value "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"

And what you need is an array with 5 elements, where each item is a number.

Example:

```
var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value.split(',')
$('#date').pickadate({
  format: 'mmmm d, yyyy',
  disable: numbers
});
```

But this code will give you an array where each item is a string, so you need to  parse each one with parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
```

Right now numbers contains a string, so you have to convert it to an array. Perhaps like this:

```
numbers = numbers.split(', ');
```

And you can do this:

```
disable: numbers
```

And not this (!):

```
disable: [
    numbers
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's your question